# What delimiter do I use to separate the string in this cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a database with this type of cell formatting in Google Sheet/Excel:

```
7-1024000032376
4-2512000032300
4-5902000032386
```

***Cell sample:***

[image]

I need to separate each string into a separate row, and not sure how to do it as there is no delimiter, nor a blank space. The no of character in each string varies between 14-16 character, so separate by fixed width doesn't work 100% of the time. Thank you for your help

Comment: Google Sheets is not Excel. Which of the two are you actually using?

Comment: Your image looks as though the values are delimited by a carriage return and or linefeed. Have you checked for Chr(10)?

Comment: Share a sample copy of google-sheet. Look like you have line feed delimeter.

Answer (score 1):

On Google Sheets: Highlight the text > Data > Split Text into Columns > Space Delimiter, then Copy the text > Paste special > Transposed

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, however this didn't work because there is no space between the string

Answer (score 0):

Not a hi-end solution but this had worked for me before.  pls try:

copy your excel column,

paste it to notepad,

then copy data you pasted in notepad and paste it to a word doc,

then copy data you pasted in word doc and paste it to excel.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable kludge/suggestion, but why the Word step?

Comment: Pasting back from notepad to excel does not work for some reason.  This is the reason.

Comment: Ah. I use Notepad++, so I guess whatever the issue with Notepad is doesn't affect that (and that's the least of the reasons I'd suggest switching).